# CSS3 strange behaviour with rendering

Tags: html, css, browser

A 1px line is appearing on different resoliutions when user hovers over the column or not. It is happening on IE11(on hover), Edge(on hover), Firefox(flickers when hover between columns) and Chrome(in center) browsers and maybe on others too. Source code is bellow and also attached images. Thanks in advance.

```css
/* reset css*/
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

.section{
 display:flex;
 flex-flow:row nowrap;
   justify-content:center;
}

.section .column{
 width:25%;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
}

.section .wrapper{
 width:100%;
 height:50%;
 padding:12.5% 7.5% 0 7.5%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   cursor:pointer;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
}

.section .bg{
   width:100%;
 height:100vh;
 transition:all 2s ease;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 background:url(https://cdn.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/iPhone6_With_iPad_PSD_template.png) center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.section .column:hover .bg{
 transform:scale3d(1.3,1.3,1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
 <div class="column">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">Some text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">Some text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">Some text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">Some text</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[On Chrome 57.0.2987.133](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gp6j.jpg)

[On Microsoft Edge 38.14393.1066.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWtD1.jpg)

Comment: check your :hover declaration. its no valid css.

Comment: I changed to .section .column .bg:hover{transform:scale(1.3);} But a problem still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding additional wrapper `<div class="container">` and changing to display table seems fixed problem on all browsers.

```css
/* reset css*/
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

.section{
 width:100%;
 display:table;
}

.section .column{
 width:25%;
 height:100vh;
 display:table-cell;
}

.section .container{
 width:100%;
    height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
}

.section .wrapper{
 width:100%;
 height:50%;
 padding:12.5% 7.5% 0 7.5%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

.section .bg{
 position:absolute;
    width:101%; /*firefox fix*/
    height:100%;
    transition:all 2s ease;
    z-index:-1;
    background:url(https://cdn.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/iPhone6_With_iPad_PSD_template.png) center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.section .column:hover .bg{
 transform:scale3d(1.3,1.3,1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
 <div class="column">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="bg"></div>
   <div class="wrapper">Some text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="bg"></div>
   <div class="wrapper">Some text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="bg"></div>
   <div class="wrapper">Some text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="bg"></div>
   <div class="wrapper">Some text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the issue looks to be the backface-visbility being hidden. I was able to reproduce your issue in Chrome, and removing backface-visibility: hidden fixed it.

```
.section .bg{
    ...
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems working fine on Chrome, but different browsers still have this problem.